# What startOfDay returns? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Someone will think the question is super easy and you could just find it on google, but I do not understand what it returns (I have already tried to search, but I did not find a clear answer)

In one of the public Github repositories, I met this line:

```
$originCurrency->updated_at->startOfDay() != Carbon::now()->startOfDay()
```

Please explain what startOfDay returns?

Comment: `2021-01-30 00:00:00`

Comment: @sta ooh, ok! Thanks a lot, so i'm stupid : (

Comment: @Rubenshtein you are welcome, since you have the answer, please remove the question